# TypeError at /empinfo/add EmployeeInfoViewset.get_empinfo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Here i was used Django Rest Framework to create simple API, But I was facing the Error on try to create new data

model.py

```
class EmpPersonalInfo(models.Model):
emp_id = models.OneToOneField(
    'Employees', models.PROTECT, primary_key=True, db_column='emp_id', verbose_name='Employee ID')
dob = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date of Birth')
mobile = models.CharField(
    max_length=10, unique=True, verbose_name='Mobile No.')
email = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True,
                         verbose_name='Email Address')
aadhar = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True,
                          verbose_name='Aadhar No.', help_text='Enter Aadhar no. without space')
pan = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, verbose_name='PAN No.')
add1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,
                        null=True, verbose_name='Address line')
city = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True,
                        null=True, verbose_name='City')
state = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True,
                         null=True, verbose_name='State')
pincode = models.IntegerField(
    blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Pincode')

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'emp_personal_info'
    verbose_name_plural = "Personal Information"

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.emp_id)
```

in my Django app i was used without id field, but in my Mysql Db table i have extra id field Auto increment but not PK, emp_id only used FK and PK here.

views.py

```
class EmployeeInfoViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):
queryset = EmpPersonalInfo.objects.all()
serializer_class = EmpInfoSerializer
lookup_field = 'emp_id'

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_empinfo(request, emp_id=None):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        if emp_id is not None:
            cursor.execute("CALL sp_get_empInfo(%s)", [emp_id])
        else:
            cursor.execute("CALL sp_get_empInfo('')")
        results = cursor.fetchall()
    employee_info = []
    for result in results:
        employee_info.append({'emp_id': result[0], 'dob': result[1], 'mobile': result[2], 'email': result[3], 'aadhar': result[4],
                             'pan': result[5], 'address1': result[6], 'city': result[7],  'state': result[8], 'pincode': result[9]})

    return JsonResponse(employee_info, safe=False)

@api_view(['POST'])
def add_empinfo(request):
    serializer = EmpInfoSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        emp_id = serializer.validated_data.get('emp_id')
        dob = serializer.validated_data.get('dob')
        mobile = serializer.validated_data.get('mobile')
        email = serializer.validated_data.get('email')
        aadhar = serializer.validated_data.get('aadhar')
        pan = serializer.validated_data.get('pan')
        add1 = serializer.validated_data.get('add1')
        city = serializer.validated_data.get('city')
        state = serializer.validated_data.get('state')
        pincode = serializer.validated_data.get('pincode')
        # Call the stored procedure with the necessary data
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.callproc('sp_add_empInfo', [
                            emp_id, dob, mobile, email, aadhar, pan, add1, city, state, pincode])
            result = cursor.fetchall()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```
path('empinfo',
     EmployeeInfoViewset.get_empinfo, name='empinfo-list'),
path('empinfo/add',
     EmployeeInfoViewset.add_empinfo, name='add_empinfo'),
```

if i run this code on my system, in browser i search url

*http://127.0.0.1:8000/empinfo/add*

i was getting below error

**TypeError at /empinfo/add
EmployeeInfoViewset.get_empinfo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'**

I tried many possible ways, still I not getting the perfect solution. Help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You likely got some other `path` with `get_empinfo`, can you share that?

Comment: `path('empinfo/<str:emp_id>', EmployeeInfoViewset.get_empinfo,
         name='Information-Detail'),`                @WillemVanOnsem this is another url i was using in my code

Comment: can you [edit] the question and *include* this path?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the paths matters, since Django will go through the paths top-to-bottom, since you have a path `empinfo/<str:emp_id>/`, it will match iwth `emp_id='add'`, you thus reorder these to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('empinfo', EmployeeInfoViewset.get_empinfo, name='empinfo-list'),
    path('empinfo/add', EmployeeInfoViewset.add_empinfo, name='add_empinfo'),
    path(
        'empinfo/<str:emp_id>',
        EmployeeInfoViewset.get_empinfo,
        name='Information-Detail',
    ),
    # …,
]
```

if `emp_id` is an integral number, you might want to change `<str:emp_id>` to `<int:emp_id>` as well.